# 'react-scripts-ts' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

When I typed `npm start`, it gives me this error message

> 'react-scripts-ts' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command

Then I tried `npm install`, it gives me a different message

> npm ERR! code ETARGET
>
> npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for adal-angular@1.0.17
>
> npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your
>    dependencies are requesting npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
>
> npm ERR! notarget
>
> npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'xxx-app'
>
> npm ERR! code ETARGET

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: npm i react-scripts-ts

Comment: please share your package.json

Answer (score 0):

as-is simply write npm install then it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).